# when trying to write file fprintf does not work

Tags: c, io

I am just trying to open and write something in file but when visual studio tries to execute fprintf program crashes here is my code

```
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* fPointer;
    fPointer = fopen_s(&fPointer,"‪C:\\asd.txt","w");
    fprintf(fPointer, "If ı can read this then ı can create for loop");
    fclose(fPointer);
    return 0;
}
```

here is the error message : 
`Access violation writing location 0x0000003A.`

Comment: watch out for compiler warnings - the return value from `fopen_s` is the wrong type to assign to `fPointer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fopen_s` return value is an error number and you overwrite your file pointer with that which you should not do.

Comment: Yes *and* that `errno_t` (zero if successful) must be checked before `fPointer` is used. See [`fopen_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019).

Comment: ı am using visual studio and fopen_s is necessary I will try to change that

Comment: @NBR perhaps you are confusing Microsoft's `fopen_s` with the standard `fopen` which does return the file pointer. In this case you have passed the *address* of the file pointer to be modified.

Comment: @NBR You can use it just save its return value to an other variable and use that for error checking. Or just do not save it at all.

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to [`fopen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-wfopen?view=vs-2019), which returns the data type `FILE *`, the function [`fopen_s`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fopen-s-wfopen-s?view=vs-2019) returns the data type `errno_t`.

In the code you posted, you pass the address of the variable `fPointer` to the function `fopen_s`, so that it will write to that variable. This is correct. However, afterwards, you explicitly assign the return value of the function `fopen_s` (which is of type `errno_t`) to the variable `fPointer`, thereby overwriting what was previously written to that variable by the function `fopen_s`. This should not be done, as the data type `errno_t` has a different meaning than the data type `FILE *`.

Also, as a general rule, you should always check whether a file was successfully opened before you use a `FILE *`.

Therefore, you should change your code to something like the following:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fPointer;
    errno_t err;

    err = fopen_s(&fPointer,"‪C:\\asd.txt","w");
    if ( err == 0 )
    {
        fprintf(fPointer, "If ı can read this then ı can create for loop");
        fclose(fPointer);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Error opening file!\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fopen_s` returns the error code if it failed to create file pointer. You have to check error value before file pointer use.